# Firestore update only queries with .where is updating everything

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

This code works to update all entries in MyCollection (MyBleeding) on firestore that have a selectedDate, not ones that are "-". I want to only update ones that have a "-". Some dates have "-" and other dates have e.g. "2020-03-29". When I use this code, it updates all dates to the current date, if they have another date or "-". Why isn't it working to query on the condition with .where and then only update those that meet that condition?
[firestore database structure with "-"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZIFL.png)
[firestore database structure with date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHE6d.png)

```
  onPress() {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true,
        });
        const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        const updateRef = firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userId)
            .collection('MyBleeding')
            .where('selectedDate', '==', '-');
        updateRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    let newRef = updateRef.doc(doc.id);
                    return newRef.update({
                        selectedDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("No such document!");
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: Based on the fix from @EmilGi, the correct code that works now:

```
onEndPress() {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true,
        });
        const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        const updateRef = firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userId)
            .collection('MyBleeding')
            .where('selectedDate', '==', '-');
        updateRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    let newRef = firebase.firestore()
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(userId)
                        .collection('MyBleeding')
                        .doc(doc.id);
                    return newRef.update({
                        selectedDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("No such document!");
                }
            })
                .then((docRef) => {
                    this.setState({
                       selectedDate: '',
                        isLoading: false,
                    });
                })
            .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                    });
                });
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you! I added it.

Comment: So, what exactly is this code doing when you run it, and how is that different than what you expect?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: Are there some dates in your database that do **not** contain "-"?

Comment: Yes, some dates have "-" and other dates have e.g. "2020-03-29". When I use this code, it updates all dates to the current date, if they have another date or "-".

Comment: I didn't understand. Please add a screenshot of the other one that does not contain "-".

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the screenshot from the "-" entry

Comment: So you say that with your code are updated also the documents that contain "2020-03-29"? Not only those only have "-", right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes exactly, all records are updating, not just those with "-".

Comment: I've reproduce it in Nodejs and received "doc is not a function" in `let newRef = updateRef.doc(doc.id);`, updated the reference properly and it worked as expected, updating only needed fields.

Comment: @EmilGi Thank you, how did you update the reference properly? I'm new to coding.

Comment: I've just created a new one from the scratch like `let newRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('MyBleeding').doc(doc.id)`, but I think you can also use doc's [ref property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref)

Comment: @EmilGi I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer as the correct one :(